# join by minimum age from 1:n

Tags: qgis, postgresql, datetime

For a gone experiment I want to link the weather data to recorded track points. The 3 layers envolved are the track layer (points), the layer of privat weather stations ("PWS" points) and a geometry-less table of weather data (each row with "PWS_id" and "datetime").

I did already hard-coded join the track points with the most closest PWS by using the NNJoin plugin.

For each PWS I do have 1-n weather records per day.

Now I need to link/join the correct weather record to the track point by minimum "age" as difference to timestamp of trackpoint.

Is there a way to solve this problem from within QGIS (without python knowledge), or if postgres/-GIS is the best solution, what would be the SQL syntax to get the record with the minimum age(track-point, weather-record).

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL provides a [DISCTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html) expression useful for your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (age) *
FROM your_joined_table
ORDER BY age DESC
```

Other possibility: [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html), something like:

```
WITH q AS (
SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY age DESC) FROM your_joined_table
) 
SELECT * FROM q WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: reading it for a second time.... but wouldnt above require an "age" field at the weather record table ?

Comment: I used "age" for the example, thinking about a timestamp field and selecting the last one.